# Does zero chemical potential (particle number nonconservation) arise as a logical consequence of zero rest mass?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, photons, mass, thermal-radiation, chemical-potential

If its number of particles of a particular type is not conserved then it has zero chemical potential. Photon number is not conserved. Hence, it has zero chemical potential. We also know that photons have zero rest mass. Does particle number nonconservation (therefore, zero chemical potential) logically follow from the 'zero rest mass property' of the particle?

Comment: "particle number nonconservation" does not mean that the chemical potential is zero; for a nonzero chemical potential, we have a *fixed average number of particles* $<N>$. If the chemical potential is zero, this simply means that there is no condition for an arbitrary fixation of the average $<N>$

Answer (score -1):

As for chemical potential, from the point of view of grand-canonical ensemble, it is a constant, coupled to the conserved number of particles:
$$
\mathcal{Z} = \text{Tr} \ e^{-\beta (H - \mu N)}
$$
The definition of chemical potential assumes the conservation of $N$. It seems not to be connected with the 'zero rest mass' property. For instance, one may consider the scalar or fermion field with the conserved $U(1)$ charge. The conservation of charge will also imply the conservation of number of particles, and one may have nonzero value for $\mu$.

Another point, maybe worth mentioning, is that the thermodynamic equilibrium requires an interaction for particles to thermalize. Photons do no interact between each other, so they cannot achieve it.

Comment: According to your last sentence, the equilibrium distribution of the blackbody radiation can not be achieved, contrarily to experience.